# Scanner keeps throwing FileNotFound Exception

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to load a file called `SPY.txt` into an array, but I can't even get this little snippet to work.

I don't understand. If `f.exists` is `true`, how can the Scanner throw a file not found exception?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File f = new File (new File("SPY.txt").getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(f.exists());
        Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
    }
}
```

Output: `True`

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable
>   source code - unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must
>   be caught or declared to be thrown    at
>   scannertest.ScannerTest.main(ScannerTest.java:13)

Line 13 is

`Scanner s = new Scanner(f);`

Comment: How are you compiling this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The clue is in the error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable
>   source code - unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException;
>   **must be caught or declared to be thrown at** scannertest.ScannerTest.main(ScannerTest.java:13)

What it means is that Scanner constructor throws an exception, so you need to place it in try/catch block, like so:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //try block starts here
        try {  
            File f = new File (new File("SPY.txt").getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println(f.exists());
            Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
        } 
        //catch the exception
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();   
        }

    }
}
```

Check the docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html)

Comment: Wow. Thank you. My original program had a try/finally. I guess I've got to read up on the try. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 5):

FileNotFoundException is a checked exception that's thrown by that particular Scanner constructor. Either declare it with a throws clause, or put a try-catch block in there.

This has nothing to do with whether the file exists or not, but everything to do with exception handling in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You are **not** getting an exception that the file is not found, you are getting an error about **Uncompilable source code** because you didn't handle an *exception*.

You have "Unhandled exception type [FileNotFoundException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html)" in:

```
new Scanner(f)
```

Solutions:

1. Surround with [`try-catch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html).
2. Declare `main` to `throw` `FileNotFoundException`.

---

```
//1
try {
    File f = new File (new File("SPY.txt").getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println(f.exists());
    Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

OR

```
//2
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
```

Comment: He isn't getting an exception at all. He is getting a compile error.

Comment: The code in your revised answer is still useless, as `s` isn't live outside the `try` block, and the word that should be italicized is not 'exception' but 'handle'.

Comment: @EJP I was only demonstrating what should be done, not providing a full code as you see.

Comment: I see, but does the OP? If you provide code it should be useful. People are going to just cut-and-paste it without the least thought.

Comment: @EJP Since I explained, writing actual code is only for demonstration, OP needs to changed small things before running the program. The most important thing for me is the concept. However, I changed it :)